# Single mysql query to show grandparents parents names and jobs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a problem with a single query where I have 3 tables

person (id primary key, name)

parent (id_of_child, id_of_father, id_of_mother) all are foreign keys (id)

job (person_id foreign key, job_title, start_date, end_date)

I should have a SELECT clause that gets the name of a child which can be changed in the query. Like:

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE id=id_of_child AND name='insert name'
```

Then also I need to extend this query to get this child's parents and grandparents and finally the grandparents' parents' names and possible jobs they have. So I should only have 8 persons names showing from the father's and mother's side.

The Parent table is kind of a relation table with data for who is who's father and mother. But I don't quite understand how I should use this table. Or how to dig to the grandparents' parents in a single query.

I am new to sql joins and thinking this through is quite hard.
I have some random data in these tables about 10 rows or more in each row.

I have tried to study sql joins from google and to think this through by myself but I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

To select parents based on a person's name without any JOINs:

```
SELECT name FROM Person
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id_of_father FROM Parent WHERE id_of_child=(SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name="Your desired name")
)
OR id IN (
    SELECT id_of_mother FROM Parent WHERE id_of_child=(SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name="Your desired name")
)
```

Translated to English:

```
I want to know the name of Persons
Who are
    The father of the person with the name "Your desired name"
Or
    The mother of the person with the name "Your desired name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up a bit more on joins in databases.

A `JOIN` combines the column values of two tables (A and B) based upon the `ON` predicate. There are different types of `JOIN`. If nothing else is specified, usually an `INNER JOIN` is used. That means that the result of the `JOIN` includes only rows, for which both tables have matching column values in the respective columns.

If your tables e.g. look like this

```
           +----+-------------+
person:    | id | name        |
           +----+-------------+
           |  1 | Alice       |
           |  2 | Bob         |
           |  3 | Alice's Mum |
           |  4 | Alice's Dad |
           |  5 | Bob's Mum   |
           |  6 | Bob's Dad   |
           +----+-------------+

           +-------------+--------------+--------------+
parent:    | id_of_child | id_of_father | id_of_mother |
           +-------------+--------------+--------------+
           |      1      |       4      |       3      |
           |      2      |       6      |       5      |
           +-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

To combine these two, you now can use an `(INNER) JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM parent  
INNER JOIN person
    ON person.id = parent.id_of_child;
```

This will give you the combination of the two tables. The `INNER JOIN` has all columns of the two source tables and yields two rows, one for each `id` in `person` that matches an `id_of_child` in `parent`.

Your result will be:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+----+-------------+
| id_of_child | id_of_father | id_of_mother | id | name        |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+----+-------------+
|      1      |       4      |       3      |  1 | Alice       |
|      2      |       6      |       5      |  2 | Bob         |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+----+-------------+
```

Since you are not interested in the ids that you joined on anymore, you can select just the subset of columns that you want (and also optionally rename them using the `AS` keyword):

```
SELECT person.name AS child, parent.id_of_father, parent.id_of_mother 
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN person
    ON person.id = parent.id_of_child;
```

resulting in:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| child       | id_of_father | id_of_mother |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Alice       |       4      |       3      |
| Bob         |       6      |       5      |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Like this, you can also join the table `person` multiple times to get the names from the father and the mother.

```
SELECT p1.name as child,
       p2.name as father,
       p3.name as mother
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN person p1
    ON p1.id = parent.id_of_child
INNER JOIN person p2
    ON p2.id = parent.id_of_father
INNER JOIN person p3
    ON p3.id = parent.id_of_mother;
```

giving you:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| child       | father       | mother       |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Alice       | Alice's Dad  | Alice's Mum  |
| Bob         | Bob's Dad    | Bob's Mum    |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I leave it to you to add the grandparents and the jobs, you should be able to get that going on from here.